# Null Value Handling in ReportParameter

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

So, in this application, the end user enters required RMA information on one form and then has the option to load it into report view and print. Because this database was put together years ago null values are in a column [Area Of Repair]. What I am needing is to figure how to set the parameter value of "area" to "unknown" if there is a null value detected. Below is the code for the current method being used.

```
public void GenerateServiceReport(string[] RMArray, string TempDataset, DataTable Results)
    {

        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "D:\\vsprojects\\projects\\emsdashboard\\emsdashboard\\RMAServiceReport.rdlc";

        ReportParameter dateReceived = new ReportParameter("DateParameter", RMArray[0]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { dateReceived });
        ReportParameter rmaNumber = new ReportParameter("RMAParameter", RMArray[1]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rmaNumber });
        ReportParameter workOrder = new ReportParameter("WorkOrderParameter", RMArray[2]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { workOrder });
        ReportParameter qty = new ReportParameter("qtyParameter", RMArray[3]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { qty });
        ReportParameter company = new ReportParameter("CompanyParameter", RMArray[4]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { company });
        ReportParameter customer = new ReportParameter("CustomerParameter", RMArray[5]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { customer });
        ReportParameter ecn = new ReportParameter("ecnParameter", RMArray[6]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { ecn });
        ReportParameter warranty = new ReportParameter("WarrantyParameter", RMArray[7]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { warranty });
        ReportParameter action = new ReportParameter("ActionParameter", RMArray[8]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { action });
        ReportParameter part = new ReportParameter("PartParameter", RMArray[9]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { part });
        ReportParameter area = new ReportParameter("AreaParameter", RMArray[10]);
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { area });

        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        serviceReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(TempDataset, Results));
        serviceReportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }
```

private void RMAServiceReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        this.serviceReportViewer.RefreshReport();
        this.serviceReportViewer.RefreshReport();
        this.serviceReportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you refresh the report 3 times in a row? Is it even necessary to refresh it?

Comment: If you want to display some special value in the report, then you have to either put the condition in the RDLC or prepare the appropriate string when filling data. Usually except for trivial conditions, I think it is simpler and cleaner to prepare the data in a format that is easy to use from the RDLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change declaring `area` variable row like this

```
ReportParameter area = new ReportParameter("AreaParameter", RMArray[10] ?? "unknown");
```

Comment: Thank you to all who have responded.